# How to combine multiple feature sets in bag of words

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, text-classification

I have text classification data with predictions depending on categories, 'descriptions' and 'components'.  I could do the classification using bag of words in python with scikit on 'descriptions'. But  I want to get predictions using both categories in bag of words with weights to individual feature sets
x = descriptions + 2* components
How should  I proceed?

Comment: You can concatenate feature sets, and you can put weights on them, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can train individual classifiers for descriptions and merchants, and obtain a final score using `score = w1 * predictions + w2 * components.`

The values of `w1` and `w2` should be obtained using cross validation.

Alternatively, you can train a single multiclass classifier by combining the training dataset.

You will now have 4 classes:

1. Neither 'predictions' nor 'components'
2. 'predictions' but not 'components'
3. not 'predictions' but 'components'
4. 'predictions' and 'components'

And you can go ahead and train as usual.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the two categories in the bag of words model itself, instead of training classifiers separately?